# Apache HttpClient 4.x - Multi-threaded execution and resource leaks

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, http, apache-commons-httpclient

**Apache HttpClient 4.2.1**

I have a Java process that downloads multiple files from one CouchDB A and uploads the same to another CouchDB B. The downloads and uploads are done using 40 worker threads using an ExecutorService.

When the file count is high (~25k) The process throws a SocketException of "too many open files" due to the Linux open file descriptor limit. I figured this might be due to a resource leak and proceeded to analyze the code which is as follows:

**Initiate worker threads**

```
 private boolean copyDocumentsFromAtoB(Array ids) {
      ExecutorService downloader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
      ExecutorService uploader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

      for (String id: ids) {
       downloader.execute(new DownloaderThread(id, downloadedDocs));
      }

      for (JsonElement doc: downloadedDocs) {
       uploader.execute(new UploaderThread(doc));
      }
    }
```

**Runnable Downloader class** (UploaderThread class has a similar implementation)

```
private static final class DocumentDownloader implements Runnable {

        private final String documentId;
        private final JsonArray downloadedDocs;

        DocumentDownloader(String documentId, JsonArray downloadedDocs) {
            this.documentId = documentId;
            this.downloadedDocs = downloadedDocs;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream docStream = null;
            String url = buildUrl(documentId);
            HttpGet doc = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                //doc.setHeaders()

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse docResponse = httpClient.execute(doc);
                docStream = docResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                //document parsing and adding to downloadedDocs. Not important
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //handle exceptions
            } finally {
                if (docStream != null) {
                    try {
                        docStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        LOGGER.debug("Cannot close input stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Findings:**

1. HttpClient is local to each thread. This is sub-optimal according to many resources and posts I found online.
2. If I did, `httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();` at the end of the Runnable class, the open file count decreased.
3. Using a global HttpClient (instantiated only once in the copyDocumentsFromAtoB method and passed down to the Runnable classes through the contructors) with a PoolingClientConnectionManager instance and a local context object, decreased the open file count further.

**Questions:**

1. Why did the original implementation have a increased number of open file descriptors during the copying process? How does multiple HttpClient instances contribute towards this?
2. Doesn't the `docStream.close();` in the `finally` block close whatever Http connection that is created between the process and the database?
3. Does the HttpClient instance get destroyed (releasing any open resources in the process) when the thread that it belongs to terminates? (This would explain why the open file count decreases after the copying process terminates prematurely)
4. Are there any other optimizations I can do (in terms of resource leaks) other than using a single global HttpClient?
5. Are there tools that I could use to obtain quantifiable statistics of this scenario for different implementations?
6. What steps can I follow to find the optimum number of worker
   threads, `setMaxTotal` and `setDefaultMaxPerRoute` (for the
   PoolingClientConnectionManager)?